# How do I kill mbuffer properly?

Tags: networking, buffer, file-io

I'm trying to use a script to send a series of files over a network from hard drive to hard drive via `mbuffer`. I've got a listening mbuffer on one computer and a sending mbuffer on the other. Things go pretty well until the time comes to send the next file.

That file sends properly, but slower, because the other mbuffer process is still listening. It doesn't append the second file onto the first, thankfully, but I'd like to be able to kill mbuffer. Just doing a `pkill`, or even a `pkill -9` causes it to become a zombie process and doesn't work the way I want it to. Is there a way for me to kill mbuffer properly, or do I just have to wait for it to time out?

Comment: A zombie process is a dead process. It's just one whose parent hasn't reaped it yet. The problem therefore is with the parent process, not mbuffer.

Comment: Killing the parent script does nothing to mbuffer, (though it says there is no controlling terminal, which tells me that I need to call it differently)

Comment: I suppose this question was inevitable but what process is launching mbuffer and how is it being called?